# @Convert is not getting called for the respository.save

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, repository, converters

I am trying to format the datetime by using  `@Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)`.
This is working as expected while saving and data is properly saved in the DB.

---

The issue I am facing is the object that's being returned while `responseEntity = myrepository.save(myEntity)` is not having the formated date. The field in the responseEntity is  still returning old format. Am I missing anything?

---

My converter class:

```
   public class DateTimeConverter implements 
    AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime attribute) {
        if(Objects.isNull(attribute)) {
            return null;
        }
        attribute =  attribute.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        return attribute.format(formatter);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if(Objects.isNull(dbData)) {
            return null;
        }
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        return LocalDateTime.parse(dbData, formatter);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your converter class

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I have posted my converter class

Comment: Do you expect `convertToEntityAttribute` to return a formatted value?

Comment: I am trying to convert the incoming date to UTC and saving in the DB. It is getting saved properly. But the return object from the repository.save() is still having old format. But if I do a findById the convertToEntityAttribute to is getting called or the UTC value is properly fetched.

Comment: The value in the return object of repository.save and the value in the Db are not the same.

Comment: `AttributeConverter` is a generic type.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar problem and discovered that the attribute conversion wasn't done by `save()` but it was done by `saveAndFlush()`. Breakpoints within the conversion weren't hit during `save()` but were by `saveAndFlush()`. If `save()` was used the conversion was hit on a subsequent `find...` query. This was also an issue if `save` should have thrown an exception as it got delayed until `flush` or subsequent query.

Answer (score 0):

`repository.save()` does return the converted value, entity value converted before flush time. It only attached to the persistence context.
But you want converted value using `convertToEntityAttribute`. `convertToEntityAttribute` only called when you fetch from the database.

Do this operation in service

```
entity.setProperty(entity.getProperty().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime());
```

Comment: By doing as you sugested it will convert all the datetime to UTC and will get saved in the DB. Just like adding the property ``spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC``. But while fetching back it will again get converted back to JVM timezone. I want to maintain the UTC time itself which is same as the DB

Comment: By default when you parse(`LocalDateTime.parse()`) it zone set as JVC timezone. You can do the same operation(Change the zone) in `convertToEntityAttribute` to maintain UTC.

Comment: Or you can set the system timezone as `UTC` also. Then you don't need this convertion.

Comment: I tried that, but what happens is when saving to DB the UTC time zone is maintained. But while when entity returned repository.save will have converted to JVM value

Comment: Did you use zone conversion in  `convertToEntityAttribute`  ? updated in answer also

Comment: If I use that again in ``convertToEntityAttribute`` when fetching from the DB in select query the time will again convert to UTC. Since its being fetched as String. Then the value UTC in Db is again converted to UTC which is wrong.

Comment: for the repository.saveAndFlush, why its not fetching the actual value thats not being saved? this would have solved my problem since in DB correct value is getting saved?

Comment: Did you check by implement the solution ?

Comment: Yes. I was doing like that. Then found the mismatch